# Create the file before downloading and complete it after downloading by double tapping on it like OneDrive in c#

Tags: c#, file, onedrive, file-management

There is a feature in OneDrive that you can see a file that is on the OneDrive site on your system **without actually having that file in your system**. And when you double click on that file, that file starts to download and you can see its contents.

I want to implement such a possibility with `C#`.
I have a site where files are uploaded.
I download the files from there and put them in a folder on my C drive.
But I want that file not to be downloaded until it is double-clicked, something similar to OneDrive.
What should I do?

[image]

I compared the FileInfo of these two files, but I didn't see any difference and I couldn't find a solution for this problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a virtual filesystem implemented using a file system driver.
There are multiple ways to implement this feature using C/C++.

But in your case, using C# means you should use third-party libraries to create a virtual files system.

There is a library called [Dokan](https://dokan-dev.github.io/), which lets you implement a full-featured virtual file system, and you have complete control over its behaviour in your C# project.

Answer (score 1):

it called "[Windows Shell namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Shell_namespace)"
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/namespace-intro

i used [EZNameSpace](https://www.ssware.com/eznamespaceextensions/eznamespaceextensions.htm) Wrapper for handling this.

there is another library called "[CBFS Shell](https://www.callback.com/cbfsshell/)" (formerly shelboost) that you can use.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a dummy file that appears to be correct but is really just a pointer to some code that downloads the correct file. Then use File.Move or File.Copy to replace the dummy file with the actual file.